# Issue with VBA ElseIf Statement

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code. I can't seem to find what's wrong with it. Whenever I run the code manually or through a button, it doesn't work nor give me an error

```
'Determine whether levels is applicable
Sub CheckLevel()

'Check for single entity first

If Range("B4").Value = 1120 Or 1120 - PC Or 1120 - L Then
    Range("B7").Value = "It's a Single Entity Level"


'Check for Legal Entity

ElseIf Range("B4").Value = 11202 Or 1120 - L4 Or 1120 - PC6 Then
    Range("B7").Value = "It's a Legal Entity Level"


'Check for Entity Group

ElseIf Range("B4").Value = 11203 Or 1120 - L5 Or 1120 - PC7 Then
     Range("B7").Value = "It's a Entity Group Level"


'Check for values that do not have a level

Else
    Range("B7").Value = "It's Not a Level"


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What value is in `B4` when you run your code?

Comment: What is PC, L, L4, PC6, L5, and PC7. You also need to put the left side into ```Or``` and ```And``` like ```Or Range("B4").Value = 1120 - L4```

Comment: `Select Case` would be much cleaner here.